# What's the best datatype in c that allows me to store a 64 bit natural number?

Tags: c

I would like to know the best datatype, in c, that would allow be to store on it a NATURAL 64 bit number.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A natural number is an integer greater than 0. Natural numbers begin at 1 and increment to infinity: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula: [Different people use different definitions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number)

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference whether the natural numbers include 0 here (but I might be wrong). The OP should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The size of data type depends on the different things, such as system architecture, compiler, and even the language. In 64 bit systems,`unsigned long`,  `unsigned long long` is of 8 bytes , so it can hold 64 bit natural number (always positive).

Please visit this link : [Size of data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690146/why-does-size-of-any-data-type-depend-on-the-machine#:%7E:text=The%20size%20of%20a%20data,language%2C%20the%20machine%20architecture%20etc.&text=For%20example%2C%20in%20C%2FC,on%20a%2064%2Dbit%20machine.)
From [<stdint.h>](https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/stdint.h.html),

```
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef unsigned long int     uint64_t;
#else
__extension__
typedef unsigned long long int    uint64_t
```

Answer (score 1):

“Natural number” may mean either [positive integer or non-negative integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number).

For the latter, the optional type `uint64_t` declared in `<stdint.h>` is an exact match for a type that can represent all 64-bit binary numerals and takes no more space than 64 bits. Support for this type is optional; the C standard does not require an implementation to provide it. There is no exact match for the former (positive integers), as all integer types in C can represent zero.

However, the question asks for the “best” type but does not define what “best” means in this question. Some possibilities are:

- If “best” means a type that can represent 64-bit binary numerals and does not take any more than 64 bits, then `uint64_t` is best.
- If “best” means a type that can represent 64-bit binary numerals and does not take any more space than other types in the implementation that can do that, then `uint_least64_t` is best.
- If “best” means a type that can represent 64-bit binary numerals and is usually fastest, then `uint_fast64_t` is best.
- If “best” means a type that can represent 64-bit binary numerals and is definitely supported, then either `uint_least64_t` or `uint_fast64_t` is best, according to whether a secondary concern is space or time, respectively.

Comment: If the implementation does not support `stdint`, then the next best solution is `unsigned long long`, which must be *at least* 64 bits wide.

Comment: @JohnBode: `<stdint.h>` is not optional.